# PDF metadata limit

Tags: pdf, ms-publisher

Is there a limit to how many metadata keyword characters are saved in a PDF? I am saving part numbers under work instructions designed in Microsoft Publisher. It will retain well past 255 characters, however when I export the document to PDF it gets cut off.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this accepted answer in the Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5500713#5500713)

In the Acrobat Family, all fields on the main Document Properties tab are limited to 1999 characters or less. Fields on the Custom Properties tab are limited to 255 characters.

However, there is no size limit mentioned in the PDF Specification, so how much is saved and displayed depends on the implementation of your PDF application.